# An attempt to understand the dimension formula.

Tags: linear-algebra

Say you have an n-dimensional vector space $V$, and a matrix transformation $T$ of the order $2\times n$. Clearly, the matrix will map $V$ to another vector space of dimension $2$. Hence $T_{[2\times n]}:V\to W$ where $\dim W=2$.

Assume that $n>3$. How do I prove that the dimension of the kernel of $T$ is $n-2$? In other words, say the basis of $V$ is $\{v_1,v_2,\dots,v_n\}$. How do I prove that the subspace generated by two of them map to non-zero vectors while the subspace generated by the rest of them map to $0$?

Comment: Can we assume that $T$ has full rank?

Comment: You'll need to know that the range of T is all of W in order to conclude that kernel has dimension (n-2). For example, what if T maps every vector in V to the 0 vector in W?

Comment: @Omnomnomnom- Yes $T$ has a rank of $2$.

Comment: If the basis of $V$ is given, then what you ask may not be true.  It is true, however, that **you can choose** a basis of $V$ with the required property.

Comment: @David- Could you explain that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The real crux of the proof comes down to the [dimension theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dimension_theorem_for_vector_spaces): the vector space $V$ has many different choices for a basis, and each basis must contain $n$ vectors.  It follows that whenever you have a set of $k\leq n$ linearly independent vectors, you can choose $n-k$ more vectors to form a basis for your space.

Now, consider the linear transformation $T$ between $V$ and $W$.  $T$ has a kernel, and that kernel must form a subspace of $V$.  As such, we must be able to select a basis $v_1,\dots,v_k$ of the kernel, and we must have $k \leq n$.

Now, $v_1,\dots,v_k$ is a linearly independent subset of $V$, so we may select vectors $u_1,\dots,u_{n-k}$ so that the set of vectors $v_i$ and $u_i$ is a basis of $V$.

Now, consider any $v \in V$.  Because the above set is a basis, we can say that
$$
v = \sum_{i=1}^k a_i v_i + \sum_{i=1}^{n-k}b_i u_i
$$
Furthermore, we have
$$
T(v) = \sum_{i=1}^k a_i T(v_i) + \sum_{i=1}^{n-k}b_i T(u_i) = 
\sum_{i=1}^{n-k}b_i T(u_i)
$$
So, every vector in the image of $T$ can be expressed as $\sum_{i=1}^{n-k}b_i T(u_i)$ for some choice of $b_i$.  Since $T$ has full rank, the image of $T$ is all of $W$, so that any $w \in W$ can be expressed as $w = \sum_{i=1}^{n-k}b_i T(u_i)$.

That is, the set $\{T(u_1),\dots,T(u_{n-k})\}$ is a set that spans $W$.  I claim that this set is also linearly independent, so that it forms a basis of $W$.

How do I know this?  Suppose this set is not linearly independent.  Then there exist coefficients $b_i$ (not all zero) so that
$$
\sum_{i=1}^{n-k}b_i T(u_i) = 0
$$
That is to say,
$$
T\left(\sum_{i=1}^{n-k}b_i u_i\right) = 0
$$
which is to say that $\sum_{i=1}^{n-k}b_i u_i$ is another vector in the kernel of $T$, which means $\sum_{i=1}^{n-k}b_i u_i$ is in the span of $\{v_1,\dots,v_k\}$, which contradicts our statement that the $v_i$ and $u_i$, together, form a basis (and are therefore linearly independent).

Since $\{T(u_1),\dots,T(u_{n-k})\}$ is a basis of $W$, it must contain $2$ elements.  Since $n-k = 2$, we conclude $k = n-2$.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Really. All these are ideas I was aware of. But the way you have brought them together is really helpful.

Comment: Glad this worked for you :)